# Google Charts Only Render when Browser Zoom At 100%

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, charts, google-visualization

Webpage contains five tabs of contents; initial tab has an account/profile form on it, three others are records for the account and the fifth one contains Google Charts with Google Analytic data in it.

The google charts are nothing complicated; a line chart, a pie chart, and two geo charts.  Using Google Chart code and standard JavaScript and PHP.  The only complicated thing was building/persisting the chart strings in a MySQL database so they could be retrieved without having the overhead of the Google Analytic call.

When first coded up the tab page, noticed the chart tab was not rendering, and that turned out to be problem where the charts would not render in a DIV where display:none.  The initial tab was display:block, but the others were display:none.  Was able to solve this by moving the DrawChart() call into the 'activate tab' code vs using the google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart) within the chart code.

This seems to work fine EXCEPT when the browser is other than 100%.

[Firefox at 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4VIk.jpg)

If you render the page at 100% and zoom the page in and out, all is fine.  However, if you set the page to other than 100%, reload the tab page, then select the metrics tab, you get a variety of results, none of which are desired.

Chrome produces the following:
[Chrome at 80%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khRS9.jpg)

Firefox is similar:
[Firefox at 80%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPbwk.jpg)

Have found one post talking about finding min/max values of each axis which I can understand if the chart boundaries are changing like zooming ONLY the chart, but with page zoom, the relative canvas is still the same size.

Here is the starting code for the GA METRIC tab and the first linechart.  Again, the drawChart() call is in tab control code so the normal callback is commented out.  This was due to the timing problem mentioned earlier.

```
<div id="GA_Metrics" class="tabcontent">
<div id="header"><span style="font-size:10px;font-weight: bold;">Record No: 007101</span></div>
<div id="postings_gametric_container_linechart" class="container"></div>
<div id="postings_gametric_container_piechart" class="container"></div>
<div id="postings_gametric_container_geoworld" class="container"></div>
<div id="postings_gametric_container_geousa" class="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart','geochart','table'],'mapsApiKey': 'keygoeshere'});
//google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawLineChart() 
{

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([[{type: 'date', label: 'Date'},

    {type: 'number', label: 'SIA49775'},
    {type: 'number', label: 'SIA51972'},
    {type: 'number', label: 'SIA52931'},
    {type: 'number', label: 'SIA53349'},
    {type: 'number', label: 'SIA53350'}],
    [new Date(2019,11,18),0,1,2,1,7],
    [new Date(2019,11,19),0,0,0,1,0],
    [new Date(2019,11,20),2,2,2,1,2],
    [new Date(2019,11,21),2,4,3,6,1],
    [new Date(2019,11,22),0,3,3,1,2],
    [new Date(2019,11,23),2,2,5,1,7],
    [new Date(2019,11,24),0,1,1,2,1],
    [new Date(2019,11,25),2,2,4,0,4],
    [new Date(2019,11,26),1,0,1,4,1],
    [new Date(2019,11,27),1,0,2,0,1],
    [new Date(2019,11,28),3,2,4,0,8],
    [new Date(2019,11,29),2,1,2,3,1],
    [new Date(2019,11,30),1,3,3,5,5],
    [new Date(2019,11,31),2,1,0,2,0],
    [new Date(2020,00,01),6,4,7,3,8],
    [new Date(2020,00,02),2,3,4,0,6],
    [new Date(2020,00,03),2,1,5,7,4],
    [new Date(2020,00,04),0,0,0,1,0],
    [new Date(2020,00,05),2,1,2,0,1],
    [new Date(2020,00,06),1,2,3,2,7],
    [new Date(2020,00,07),0,1,0,3,2],
    [new Date(2020,00,08),1,1,4,0,4],
    [new Date(2020,00,09),1,1,2,1,4],
    [new Date(2020,00,10),3,2,4,2,9],
    [new Date(2020,00,11),2,5,2,2,6],
    [new Date(2020,00,12),0,0,1,1,1],
    [new Date(2020,00,13),2,2,3,0,6],
    [new Date(2020,00,14),4,4,2,3,8],
    [new Date(2020,00,15),3,3,3,2,3],
    [new Date(2020,00,16),0,3,2,1,1]]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Active Posting(s) PageViews (Last 30 Days)',
        hAxis: {
                  format: 'M/d',
                  gridlines: {color: '#000080'}
               },
        vAxis: {
                  title: 'Page Views',
                  gridlines: {color: '#000080'}
               },
        pointSize: 3,
        backgroundColor: '#cfcfcf',
        chartArea:{width:'62%'}
};

/* Create instance of "Classic" Visualization Line Chart  */
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('postings_gametric_container_linechart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Here is the code further down on the page that controls the tabs.  This is where the drawChart() call had to go to avoid the display:none issue mentioned above.

```
<script>
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
  //Moved the drawChart() call to this location so the call to render the chart comes AFTER the
  //DIV is visible, otherwise, the chart does not render properly.  See DECLARATION for explanation.
  if(pageName == "GA_Metrics")
  {
      drawLineChart();
      drawPieChart();
      drawGeoWorldMap();
      drawGeoUSAMap();
  }
}
```

Googled the error messages in red for Chrome and Firefox which provided some details but nothing seemed to fit this problem.  When the page is zoomed in or out and then reloaded, the drawChart() call happens again when you select the GA METRICS tab, so thought it would render appropriately, but alas not.

Thank you in advance for any possible solutions.

LarryG

UPDATE 20200211_1220C

Another interesting tidbit, using the Firefox Web Developer Tool, the DIV with the chart has a height of 1px.  However, if you click on the GA METRIC tab (page not reloaded, but the openPage() call occurs passing in the GA METRIC tab), each time the height grows 1px. Therefore, after 40 clicks you can begin to see the charts form, so they are there ... the DIV height is just getting overridden when the zoom is not at 100%.  See graphic link.

[Firefox at 80% after 40 clicks of GA METRIC tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piJw3.jpg)

20200214 UPDATE - Added code from affected page, cutting out all that was not necessary.  This shows the relative placement of the tab control vs the openPage() and the metric charts.  The openPage() is below the tab controls.  Only thing below it is the footers and such.

```html
<!-- DIV STARTS HERE -->
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Account_Info', this, '#000080')" id="defaultOpen">Account Info</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Posts_Active', this, '#000080')">ACTIVE</button>
<button class="tablink" style="opacity:1.0;" onclick="openPage('Posts_SOLD', this, '#000080')">SOLD</button>
<button class="tablink" style="opacity:1.0;" onclick="openPage('Posts_NotSOLD', this, '#000080')">NOT SOLD</button>
<button class="tablink" style="opacity:1.0;" onclick="openPage('GA_Metrics', this, '#000080')">GA Metrics</button>

<div id="Account_Info" class="tabcontent">
</div>

<div id="Posts_Active" class="tabcontent">
</div>

<div id="Posts_SOLD" class="tabcontent">
</div>

<div id="Posts_NotSOLD" class="tabcontent">
</div>

<div id="GA_Metrics" class="tabcontent">
<div id="header"><span style="font-size:10px;font-weight: bold;">Record No: 019036</span></div>
<div id="postings_gametric_container_linechart" class="container"></div>
<div id="postings_gametric_container_piechart" class="container"></div>
<div id="postings_gametric_container_geoworld" class="container"></div>
<div id="postings_gametric_container_geousa" class="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.  "mapsApiKey" is the property name and is required no matter what you call your Key.
    // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart','geochart','table'],'mapsApiKey': 'API_KEY_GOES_HERE'});

    //20190304LG: Noticed the chart was not rendering properly. Found StackOverFlow article where if the charts are in a "display:none" div like a tab
    //they will not render properly.  They will revert to google chart css which is usually 400x200px.  The solution was to either make the
    //chart call before the tabs/divs were set to display:none OR load them when the tab/div was activated.  As a result, LG commented out
    //the next line and put the drawChart() call in the ACCOUNT_MGMNT_TEMP.HTML file in the openPage() Javascript function.  This seems to 
    //have fixed the problem.
    //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    //
    //20200209LG: The Geo Strings sometimes contain an apostrophe such as ['Provence-Alpes-Cote d'Azur',1] which will prevent rendering.
    //            Added some str_replace code to escape those instances, but its bruteforce for now.

    function drawLineChart() 
    {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([[{type: 'date', label: 'Date'},
{type: 'number', label: 'SIA35512'},
{type: 'number', label: 'SIA39964'},
{type: 'number', label: 'SIA53391'}],
[new Date(2020,00,14),0,0,1],
[new Date(2020,00,15),0,0,0],
[new Date(2020,00,16),1,2,0],
[new Date(2020,00,17),0,0,0],
[new Date(2020,00,18),1,0,0],
[new Date(2020,00,19),0,1,0],
[new Date(2020,00,20),3,4,0],
[new Date(2020,00,21),2,3,1],
[new Date(2020,00,22),1,0,0],
[new Date(2020,00,23),1,0,0],
[new Date(2020,00,24),2,0,0],
[new Date(2020,00,25),0,0,0],
[new Date(2020,00,26),0,4,0],
[new Date(2020,00,27),6,0,0],
[new Date(2020,00,28),2,1,0],
[new Date(2020,00,29),1,0,0],
[new Date(2020,00,30),0,0,0],
[new Date(2020,00,31),1,1,0],
[new Date(2020,01,01),0,1,1],
[new Date(2020,01,02),0,1,0],
[new Date(2020,01,03),1,2,2],
[new Date(2020,01,04),3,2,1],
[new Date(2020,01,05),1,0,0],
[new Date(2020,01,06),0,1,0],
[new Date(2020,01,07),0,0,0],
[new Date(2020,01,08),1,1,0],
[new Date(2020,01,09),0,1,0],
[new Date(2020,01,10),1,0,0],
[new Date(2020,01,11),0,2,0],
[new Date(2020,01,12),2,0,0]]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Active Posting(s) PageViews (Last 30 Days)',
            hAxis: {
                format: 'M/d',
                gridlines: {color: '#000080'}
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Page Views',
                gridlines: {color: '#000080'}
            },
            pointSize: 3,
            backgroundColor: '#cfcfcf',
            chartArea:{width:'62%'}
        };

        /* Create instance of "Classic" Visualization Line Chart  */
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('postings_gametric_container_linechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawPieChart() 
    {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Posting','Page Views'],
['35512',1395],
['39964',645],
['53391',80]]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Active Posting(s) % PageViews (Last 30 Days)',
            backgroundColor: '#cfcfcf',
            is3D: true
        };

        //Create instance of "Classic" Visualization Line Chart  
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('postings_gametric_container_piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    //20190321 LG - REPLACE the chart.draw with the geomap.draw.  SEE this URL or your TEST_geo2.html file

    function drawGeoWorldMap() 
    {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Country','PageViews'],
['Australia',8],
['Belgium',11],
['Brazil',3],
['Canada',64],
['Czechia',8],
['Ecuador',3],
['Georgia',3],
['Germany',3],
['Italy',3],
['Malaysia',3],
['Mexico',3],
['New Zealand',3],
['Puerto Rico',3],
['Singapore',3],
['South Korea',3],
['United Kingdom',3],
['United States',1227]]);

        var options = {
        region: 'world',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        backgroundColor: '#cfcfcf',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('postings_gametric_container_geoworld'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

    }

    function drawGeoUSAMap() 
    {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['State','PageViews'],
['(not set)',3],
['Aguadilla',3],
['Alabama',11],
['Alberta',3],
['Arizona',5],
['Arkansas',3],
['British Columbia',24],
['California',80],
['Canterbury',3],
['Colorado',16],
['Connecticut',37],
['District of Columbia',13],
['England',3],
['Flanders',11],
['Florida',61],
['Georgia',27],
['Guayas',3],
['Gyeonggi-do',3],
['Idaho',34],
['Illinois',16],
['Indiana',50],
['Iowa',5],
['Kansas',13],
['Kentucky',8],
['Liberec Region',5],
['Maine',16],
['Massachusetts',29],
['Michigan',85],
['Minnesota',50],
['Mississippi',8],
['Missouri',77],
['Montana',8],
['Nebraska',16],
['Nevada',3],
['New Hampshire',29],
['New Jersey',11],
['New South Wales',3],
['New York',101],
['North Carolina',32],
['North Dakota',11],
['Nova Scotia',5],
['Ohio',66],
['Oklahoma',5],
['Ontario',27],
['Oregon',13],
['Pennsylvania',56],
['Prague',3],
['Puebla',3],
['Quebec',5],
['Queensland',3],
['Rhineland-Palatinate',3],
['Rhode Island',5],
['Samegrelo-Zemo Svaneti',3],
['Selangor',3],
['Sicily',3],
['South Carolina',5],
['State of Sao Paulo',3],
['Tennessee',27],
['Texas',61],
['Utah',8],
['Vermont',3],
['Victoria',3],
['Virginia',21],
['Washington',27],
['West Virginia',3],
['Wisconsin',74]]);

        var options = {
        region: 'US',
        backgroundColor: '#cfcfcf',
        resolution: 'provinces',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('postings_gametric_container_geousa'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

    }

/*    
    function drawGeoUSACityMap() 
    {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([<!--GA_METRIC_GEOUSACITY_CALL-->]);

        var options = {
        region: 'US',
        backgroundColor: '#cfcfcf',
        displayMode: 'markers',
        resolution: 'metros',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('postings_gametric_container_geousacity'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
*/

</script>
</div>

<script>
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
  //Moved the drawChart() call to this location so the call to render the chart comes AFTER the
  //DIV is visible, otherwise, the chart does not render properly.  See DECLARATION for explanation.
  if(pageName == "GA_Metrics")
  {
      drawLineChart();
      drawPieChart();
      drawGeoWorldMap();
      drawGeoUSAMap();
  }
}

//INITIALIZATION of the TABS ... get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>

<!-- DIV ENDS HERE -->
```

Comment: where is `openPage` called? are you waiting for the page to completely load beforehand?

Comment: @WhiteHat ... thanks for responding.

The openPage() is called each time your click on a tab ... it is what activates (display:block) the tab, and display:none the other tabs.  

Here is an interesting twist ... found that the DIV with each chart object in it, starts out at 1px height, and with each click of the GA METRIC tab, the height increases by 1px.  There after clicking it X times, you can actually start to see the chart again.

Comment: thanks, there could be a number of things that are causing this issue. it will be hard to answer without all of the code. at least up to the point the tab click event is assigned (`openPage`) -- are you listening for the window load event, or jquery's `$(document).ready`?

Comment: @WhiteHat ... easiest way to do that is to let you see it realtime.  Go to the following webpage and use the CONTACT page.  With an email, I will send you your credentials.
https://www.ski-it-again.com/php/skiitagain.php?endless=summer&topic=contact

Comment: @WhiteHat ... realized I did not answer your questions above.  All tab content is on one page.  This allows the gstatic and google.charts.load libraries to load prior to clicking on the tab with the charts (ie GA METRIC tab).  The drawChart() call comes when you click on the tab and is part of the openPage() call which is at the top of the page.  Not using the load or jquery events directly for the chart loading since the delay between page load (initializing on a different tab) and clicking on the GA METRIC tab usually is a few seconds.  Not the best design, but not affecting this zoom issue.

Comment: I was asking about when the `openPage` event handler is assigned and / or called for the first time. Looking at the error message you received regarding `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` -- this is most likely because the page has not fully loaded and the script cannot find the `"tabcontent"` or `"tablink"` elements. google's `load` statement will wait for the page to load by default. if you wait for the callback, or the promise it returns, this will prevent the error from occurring -- and most likely resolve your issue...

Comment: @WhiteHat ... posting updated with pertinent code, cutting out HTML above and below.  Just showing DIVs of the tab control on the page.  The tabs are defined at the top.  Tab content in the middle.  openPage() function which sets tab DIV to  visible or not.  And lastly, tab initialization ... click() event.   Would agree about timing but this problem only seems to occur when page is Zoomed to value other than 100% (mostly smaller) will cause the rendering problem.  Hence, the reason timing would not seem to be an issue, since it seems to work at 100% with no issues.  THANK YOU!

Comment: I'm experiencing this same behaviour in Chrome 109. Did you ever get to the bottom of it? I can work around it by setting a height on the 'div' which the chart targets using CSS, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Philip,  Been long enough I do not recall explicitly but I did put a comment into the code at the bottom that states "Moved the drawChart() call to this location so the call to render the chart comes AFTER the DIV is visible, otherwise, the chart does not render properly."   Comment says to look in the DECLARATION so will post that below as it made this entry too long.  That has some more clues as to what was done to help the problem.

Comment: 20190304LG: Noticed the chart was not rendering properly. Found StackOverFlow article where if the charts are in a "display:none" div like a tab they will not render properly.  They will revert to google chart css which is usually 400x200px.  The solution was to either make the chart call before the tabs/divs were set to display:none OR load them when the tab/div was activated.  As a result, commented out the next line (//google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);) and put the drawChart() call in the ACCOUNT_MGMNT_TEMP.HTML file in the openPage() Javascript function.